# My neural networks predict is giving me an error: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, data-analysis

I am doing a simple ham/spam text classification. My Keras NN trained and evaluated properly; however, when I try to predict a new text in the following format, I get a "IndexError: list index out of range" error:

```
model.predict(cleaning_funcs('my bus departs in five minutes'))
```

I also used the following if this is of any help:

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=5000)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(x_train)

x_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x_train)
x_test = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x_test)

vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
print(x_train[2])

from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
maxlen = 100
x_train = pad_sequences(x_train, padding='post', maxlen=maxlen)
x_test = pad_sequences(x_test, padding='post', maxlen=maxlen)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your cleaning_funcs doesn't return an array, the predict function expect an array try

```
model.predict([cleaning_funcs('my bus departs in five minutes')])
```

more info https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict

Comment: Thank you! You did point me into the right direction. Cheers

Comment: You can post yourself the right answer and mark it as the fix to help the community if this answer doesn't exactly fit your question.

Comment: Seems to work if i do: model.predict(pad_sequences(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([cleaning_funcs('my bus departs in five minutes')]), padding='post', maxlen=maxlen)).round()

Comment: Ah ok I understand ! I thought the cleaning_funcs was doing that kind of processing. Perfect if it works for you !